# Why is "ExecuteWcfOperation: http://tempuri.org/ISPWindowsTokenCacheServiceContract/CacheHandle" slow to execute?

Tags: search, warm-up

I am currently using a warmup script to preload the pages of my sites. The warmup works well but about 2 minutes after it ran the search becomes slow again. I have refreshed the page with the developer dashboard enabled and I can see which part is slow but I have no idea how I can prevent this rendering step to slow down. I'm using SharePoint 2010.

Why does "ExecuteWcfOperation:http://tempuri.org/ISPWindowsTokenCacheServiceContract/CacheHandle" takes 24 seconds to execute ?

- Activate web part connections (0.05 ms)

- Panneau d'affinement
  CreateChildControls (24226.22
            ms)
  - DataBinding DataFormWebPart (Panneau d'affinement) (24226.00 ms)
    - RefinementManager.GetRefinementXml() (24121.95
                    ms)
      - SharePointSearchRuntime::SendRequest (24117.62
                        ms)
        - SharePointSearchRuntime::GetQueryResult (24117.03
                            ms)
          - CreateChannelActingAsLoggedOnUser:Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.ISearchServiceApplication (24086.46
                                ms)
            - GetServiceSecurityToken (24086.19 
              ms)
              - CacheHandle (24085.90 ms)
                - CreateChannelActingAsLoggedOnUser:Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.ISPWindowsTokenCacheServiceContract (0.32
                                            ms)
                  - GetServiceSecurityToken (0.04
                                              ms)
                  - CreateChannelWithIssuedToken (0.15
                                                ms)
                - InitializeWcfOperation (0.02
                  ms)
                - **ExecuteWcfOperation:http://tempuri.org/ISPWindowsTokenCacheServiceContract/CacheHandle (24084.56
                                            ms)**
                  - CleanUpWcfOperation (0.01
                                          ms)
            - CreateChannelWithIssuedToken (0.16
                                ms)
          - Execute (29.21 ms)
            - InitializeWcfOperation (0.03 
              ms)
            - ExecuteWcfOperation:http://tempuri.org/ISearchQueryServiceApplication
              /Execute (26.46
                                    ms)
              - CleanUpWcfOperation (0.01
                ms)
          - RecordQuery (0.08 ms)
            - EnqueueRecordQuery (0.02
              ms)
        - SharePointSearchRuntime::MakeSharepointXmlResult (0.03
                            ms)
        - SharePointSearchRuntime::MakeSharepointXmlResult#1 (0.02
                            ms)
      - RefinementManager.GetRefinement(Dictionary<string,
                        Dictionary<string, RefinementDataElement>>,
                        XmlDocument, int) (1.52 
        ms)

- Panneau d'affinement OnPreRender (2.85 
  ms)

Comment: When you say "search becomes slow again" does that mean that it was fast right after the warm-up script?  Does your warm-up script call search?  I ask because many of the warm up scripts I've seen do not touch farm services like search, managed meta-data, or bcs.

Comment: Yes, right after the warm-up the search is fast. I'm using this warm-up script [PowerShell Warmup Script 2](http://nearbaseline.com.au/blog/2010/02/powershell-warmup-script-2/). In the extrasites file I added these links (I translated the Search folder from French so I'm not sure the path is good on an English based SP): http://.../Search, http://.../Search/Pages/default.aspx, http://.../Search/Pages/results.aspx, http://.../Search/Pages/results.aspx?k=a

Comment: what's the makeup of your farm? is the query service running on the web front end or on a seperate app server?

Comment: This is my development server, everything is running on the same machine (SP + SQL Server). But my production environment has the same problem and SQL Server is installed on a separate machine for the production farm.

Comment: This sounds like it could be an authentication problem. Are you relying on an external domain controller?

Comment: @SPDoctor: No, we are not relying on an external domain controller.

Comment: Interestingly the same issue was asked on the MSDN site and has not been answered yet - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/sharepoint2010general/thread/202e0536-4121-4358-b66f-4f5e301fb29a

Answer (score 1):

It *could* have something to do with CRL verification when you have a proxy or similar, from what I've experienced.

Add the following to your hosts file to "bypass" the CRL stuff:

```
127.0.0.1       crl.microsoft.com
```